# Aggregate time series by change events on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, time-series, ethereum

On BigQuery I have a timeseries of data that represents snapshots of an DEX pool on Ethereum. Each row has a timestamp, a pool address, and a balance. I need a query that returns the list of rows only when the balance changes.

So for example having the following rows:

```
 ts | pool  | balance
------------------------------
 1  | 0x123 | 100
 2  | 0x123 | 100
 3  | 0x123 | 80
 4  | 0x123 | 80
 5  | 0x123 | 100
```

The query would return:

```
 ts | pool  | balance
------------------------------
 1  | 0x123 | 100
 3  | 0x123 | 80
 5  | 0x123 | 100
```

Can I get some help?

Answer (score 3):

Consider below option

```
select * from pools where true 
qualify ifnull(balance != lag(balance) over win, true)
window win as (partition by pool order by ts)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As I was writing and simplifying my problem I end up solving it myself :)

So here's the query I wrote, hope it will help you solve similar problems:

```sql
WITH pools AS (
    SELECT 1 as ts, "a" as pool, 100 as balance UNION ALL 
    SELECT 2 as ts, "a" as pool, 100 as balance UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3 as ts, "a" as pool, 80 as balance UNION ALL 
    SELECT 4 as ts, "a" as pool, 80 as balance UNION ALL 
    SELECT 5 as ts, "a" as pool, 100 as balance
),
data AS (
    SELECT pool, ts, balance, (LAG(ts) OVER (PARTITION BY pool ORDER BY ts ASC)) AS prev_ts,
        (LAG(balance) OVER (PARTITION BY pool ORDER BY ts ASC)) AS prev_balance
    FROM pools
    ORDER BY ts
)
SELECT ts, pool, balance, prev_balance 
FROM data
WHERE balance != prev_balance or prev_balance is NULL
```